# How can I look up or create a shortcut?

Tags: customization, shortcut

The edge slide function for example is only available through *edge tool menu* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>) or the *search tool* (<kbd>Space</kbd>)

[image: Searching for the Edge Slide Tool]

When searching for "slide" in the *preferences / input-tab* no reference is found. When I try to add a new one I'm not able to map that function to a shortcut.

Can this be achieved another way?

[image: Searching for Slide in the preferences.]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Edge slide is indeed a special case, triggered through double G (grab mode -> edge slide). For this reason it doesn't show a key map entry.

You can however assign it yourself a key in the input configuration of user preferences. Under 3D View open the Mesh operator tree, scroll down and press Add New. In the first box write "transform.edge_slide", and give a key or key combo to trigger this. After that you should see the shortkey in the operator search menu as well. In the example image below I've used the equal sign.

[image: Edge Slide manually assigned hotkey. Equal sign in image]

Comment: double G actually does a vertex slide that depends on context. you can also get vert slide with ctrl+V in edit mode > vertex slide. for edge slide you can do ctrl+F > edge slide. Both you can create shortcuts for by right clicking in the ctrl+V/F menu

Comment: How did you know that transform.edge_slide was the right keyword? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @Mike I know this is late, but for the benefit of those in the future: it's in the [python api...](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.transform.html#bpy.ops.transform.edge_slide)

Answer (score 12):

*It's actually not only defined there, selecting an edge and bringing up the shelf on the left with <kbd>T</kbd>, you can find it under Deform, refer to the 2nd image below. This is with 2.67a btw so this might be a recent addition.*

You can also *Right Click* on the a button in Blender to change or lookup the relevant shortcut.

[image]

*or* if none is already present add one.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you are using recent blender 2.67 or 2.67a, you can call edge slide by pressing double <kbd>G</kbd> while edge selected.

Additionally you can use add-on, for this purpose I recommend [Quick Tools Add-on by Jonathan Williamson from CGCookie](https://github.com/CGCookie/script-bakery/tree/master/release).

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of Blender, and probably older ones, you can right-click a function and get the option "change shortcut" or "add-shortcut" Then you can move your mouse cursor over that option and press whatever keyboard key or key combination you want to be the new shortcut.