# Scale Vertices for Skin Modifier with Industry compatible shortcuts

Tags: modifiers

when working with the skin modifier there was a shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd>) to change the radius of vertices.

How can I do this using the industry compatible shortcuts in Blender 2.8?

Comment: Did you try that same Ctrl+A? There were many shortcuts changed or disabled but this one seems to be the same

Comment: I use the "Industry compatible shortcuts" - Ctrl+A is select all.

Comment: What is the question then? What is meant by "industry compatible shortcuts" then? I load factory settings for 2.8 (since I do not use defaults in it) and I have Ctrl+A as editing radius for Skin modifier (in Edit mode). If you want to stay on industry compatible shortcuts, you will need adapt other actions to new shortcuts (edit if shortcut exist for editing Skin radius or create new one), or you don't adapt and don't use industry compatible ones.

Comment: if you cannot for some reason press control+A then just create a new shortcut.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143/how-can-i-look-up-or-create-a-shortcut#148

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Mac it's <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>